# Secure way to store client information and send back to client - java spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, cordova, file-upload

I am developing web service for a mobile application.As a part of this, I need to create some confidential reports and store it in the server and send it back to client on request as links (from which the file can be downloaded) . The requirement is , they should be able to open and view the documents in mobile.

1. If I have to send the file links, I should be having it in a web application which provides a public url . But does that make the reports secure ?
2. Can I send it as multipart file instead of url? In that case the problem is hybrid (phonegap ) platform cannot directly access the files. Is there any way to do it on phonegap?
3. If I use any encryption technique , may be like encrypting the url , the actual url can still be seen from the browser which  opens inline .

Can anyone suggest a effective way to do send confidential documents to mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating and storing the report structure in PDF format on the server. Most browsers on mobile open up pdf files directly within the browser. 
Since these are PDF files, you can password protect these and only clients who know the password can view the files. 
Alternatively you can have a login filter, so that whenever a client hits your web service, he first enters some valid credentials to gain access to the document.
Encrypting the URL gives no benefit as the resource you intend to secure is the information in the document served back to the client.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this without secure passwords ? Secure passwords did not convince my Boss. He says we cannot expect so much out a end user

Comment: Are the end users known before hand ?? As in do you know which personnel are going to access this report ??

Comment: This s something like a health app. So, normal people who sign up for health services are the end users.

Comment: Perfect !! Then the answer lies within your application itself :). You mentioned, "people who sign up", therefore while signing up, they will be providing with their email ids (since that might also be used for password recovery incase of forgotten passwords and such purposes). So you have two unique approaches. First password protect the pdf with the same password the users use for logging into the app. Second approach is send them their "report" to their registered email accounts whenever they access your service link. Let me know incase of any further queries. :)